# No se obtiene respuesta de método php

Tags: php, ajax

Acabo de empezar esta semana con PHP y algo de ajax y no se donde puede estar el error que tengo.

Código:

```
function cartaExistente(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'../../ajax/funcionesAjax.php',
        type: "post",
        //datatype: "json",

        data: {action: "existeCarta", nombre:$('#nombre')[0].value, expansion:$('#expansion')[0].value},

        success: function (response) {
           /* var datos = JSON.parse(data);*/
           //alert(response);
           $result = $.trim(response);
            $('#cartaExistente').html($result);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });   
}
```

método que ejecuta y manda la respuesta:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if($action == "existeCarta"){
            existeCarta($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['expansion']);
        }
    }

    function existeCarta($nombre,$expansion){
        $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "prueba") or die("Error al conectar a la bbdd");
        $request= mysqli_query($conexion, "select nombre,rareza,expansion,cantidad from prueba where nombre = '".$nombre."' 
                                and expansion = '".$expansion."'")
            or die ("Error al buscar los datos");


        $display_string = "<table>";
        $display_string .= "<tr>";
        $display_string .= "<th>Nombre</th>";
        $display_string .= "<th>Expansion</th>";
        $display_string .= "<th>Rareza</th>";
        $display_string .= "<th>Cantidad</th>";
        $display_string .= "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($request)) {
            $display_string .= "<tr>";
            $display_string .= "<td>$row[nombre]</td>";
            $display_string .= "<td>$row[expansion]</td>";
            $display_string .= "<td>$row[rareza]</td>";
            $display_string .= "<td>$row[cantidad]</td>";
            $display_string .= "</tr>";
         }

        $display_string .= "</table>";
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        return $display_string;
    }
?>
```

Mi problema es que al intentar obtener la respuesta en el response:

```
success: function (response) {
       /* var datos = JSON.parse(data);*/
       //alert(response);
       $result = $.trim(response);
       $('#cartaExistente').html($result);
},
```

este me sale en blanco y no me pinta en la pantalla lo que necesito. Como ya he dicho antes, llevo poco tiempo y no se que puede estar mal. Alguna solución??

Comment: si quieres tener una respuestas desde php, para que puedas leerla desde ajax. solo debes poner 

 echo json_encode($display_string);

Comment: Prueba a cambiar return $display_string; por echo $display_string; porque a veces el return no es válido.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. El `alert` que tienes comentado, ¿si lo activas `alert(response);` muestra algo? En tu HTML hay un contenedor o elemento cuyo  `id`  sea `cartaExistente`?

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper eso es cuando `datatype: "json"` , actualmente no es así, esa parte está comentada en el código. Y hay que decir que en ese caso habría que crear un array para mandarlo con `json_encode`.

Comment: oh si cierto, no leí  esa parte del código, pero solo basta con poner  echo   y lo tendrás del otro lado.

Comment: @A.Cedano muestra un vació, nada mas. Por otro lado si que tengo un contenedor con ese id.

Comment: @AlexBurkeCooper entonces pongo el echo, como debería quedar el success?? lo del echo lo había probado antes y si lo muestra pero pensaba que tenia que llegar ese dato al response y desde hay enviarlo al html.

Comment: ¿La URL del PHP es correcta? En el PHP pon un `else` con algo como `echo "No se postearon datos";` Deberías verificar también la conexión y demás cosas. Faltan controles en tu código PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no estás recogiendo ni enviando el valor de la función... para que te funcione deberías dejar el primer bloque más o menos así:

```php
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        if($action == "existeCarta"){
            $result = existeCarta($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['expansion']);
            echo $result;
        } else {
            echo "<p>no hay datos</p>";   // De esta forma te aseguras de enviar
        }                                 // siempre una respuesta
    } else {
        echo "<p>no hay datos</p>";
    }
```